# visual studio code drag from browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to drag and drop HTML-nodes from browser to VSCode?

Reason:
I created a (web-) page which lets you drag and drop a node's outerHTML (as text) - using common Javascript drag and drop.

This works fine together with all kinds of text-editors, but I can't get Visual Studio Code to accept the dragged text.

VSCode recognizes the drag, but when I drop it, the VSCode editor remains empty.

(Version 1.30.1 (1.30.1) MacOS X 10.14.3)

Comment: install extensions, like notepad++ or sublime, it'll have all the features.

Comment: What do you mean? As I've said: it works fine in Sublime, BBEdit, but not in VSCode - that's what the question is all about (btw: there's no notepad++ on the mac)

Comment: VScode has extensions like sublime, notepad++.. etc, which copy their features of them

Comment: if you stype Ctrl+Shift+X, it'll open extensions. you can search notepad++ or sublime which has this feature which you require.

Comment: Nope - not on Mac; since there's no notepad++ on Mac you can just install some keybindings and themes - that's it. (btw: the extensions-pane is opened using CMD-SHIFT-X on the Mac)